# custom error message for assertThat() in junit?

Tags: java, junit

I was wondering if assertThat() has a way of adding a custom error message ?

for example in this :

```
assertThat(file.exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
```

I would like to add some custom message, saying which file name doesnt exist

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would prefer the following, to avoid the reader believing that you wish to assert that the file name doesn't exist..!

```
assertThat("File name should exist", file.exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
```

Comment: In which world does this work? What libraries has to be imported?

Comment: The import you would use depends on the version of JUnit. E.g. https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)

Answer (score 13):

Use the overloaded [`assertThat`](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) method

```
assertThat("File name doesn't exist", file.exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
```

Comment: Mind the readability! When you read it: "assert that file name doesn't exist ..." ... it's the opposite that you actually test!

Answer (score 5):

You may want to simply use the `assertTrue()` methods with 2 args:

```
Assert.assertTrue("File "+file.getAbsoluePath()+"does not exist", file.exists());
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this, since one can read it as a sentence: "assert that file 'myFile' exist: myFile exists is true"

```
assertThat("File '" + myFile + "' exists", myFile.exists(), is(true));
```

And one gets also readable message with all necessary information when it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: File '/blah' exists
Expected: is <true>
     but: was <false>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method :

```java
Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> myTestedObject.funtion());
assertThat("Error Message", thrown, isInstanceOf(MyException.class));
```